# How to avoid redundancy here?

Tags: ellipsis

"When I finally caught him, he was bleeding and was too weak to swim."

The sentence seems awkward to me and I don't know how to rephrase it. I think "was" is kinda redundant but just omitting it doesn't help the sentence much. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should drop the second "was". Then it reads fine.

Comment: Such _ellipsis_ is quite normal, common and acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no redundancy here. It is perfectly correct. Optionally, if at all you want to shorten the sentence without changing the meaning, you could try this :

> **"When I finally caught him, he was bleeding and too weak to swim."**

But your sentence doesn't have an *'intolerable redundancy issue'*. You needn't make any modifications whatsoever. So, you're good to go.